# Can't apply template to child element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have am XML file that contains a child element nested within another element inside a `<p>` element. My XSLT is pulling the `<p>` element fine, but it's ignoring the `<span>`. I know it has something to do with the xPath, but I can't figure out how to do it with this XSLT structure.

```
<newsItem>
<inlineXml>
<h2>Calendar</h2> 
 <p><strong><span class="dates">June 16-18:</span>National Conference, Denver</strong></p>
 <p><strong><span class="dates">June 19-21:</span>Local Event, Chicago</strong></p>
<inlineXml>
</newsItem>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="newsItem">
 <newsItem><xsl:apply-templates/></newsItem>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="h2">
 <h2><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></h2>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/strong/span">
 <date><xsl:value-of select="."/></date>
 </xsl:template> 

 <xsl:template match="p">
 <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the desired result:

```
<newsItem>
<inlineXml>
<h2>Calendar</h2> 
 <p><date>June 16-18:</date>National Conference, Denver</p>
 <p><date>June 19-21:</date>Local Event, Chicago</p>
<inlineXml>
</newsItem>
```

This is probably very simple, but it's stumping me.

Thanks

Comment: If I remove the template for "p" the span template works, but I can't get both templates to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
   <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

your result will become:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<newsItem>
  <h2>Calendar</h2>
  <p><date>June 16-18:</date>National Conference, Denver</p>
  <p><date>June 19-21:</date>Local Event, Chicago</p>
</newsItem>
```

which is very close to the expected result, except the `<inlineXml>` wrapper is missing. This is because there's no template matching it, so if you add:

```
<xsl:template match="inlineXml">
   <inlineXml><xsl:apply-templates/></inlineXml>
</xsl:template>
```

you will get the expected result exactly.

---

Note that now you have three very similar templates:

```
<xsl:template match="newsItem">
   <newsItem><xsl:apply-templates/></newsItem>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="inlineXml">
   <inlineXml><xsl:apply-templates/></inlineXml>
</xsl:template>
```

which could be rolled together into one:

```
<xsl:template match="newsItem | inlineXml | p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform

Comment: What you are missing is the correct treatment of the `strong` element.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin No, I don't think so. I believe you are missing the built-in template rules.

Comment: In the above example you ask me to take out the normalize-space function. That allows me to pull the "date" info, but the data has a bunch of extra spaces in it. How can I strip that space out now?

Comment: I added the following template and it seems to work to strip the extra space out of the elements: `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:template>`

Comment: @JimMaivald That is the correct solution. And you can add `h2` to the "generic" template, too.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Inline XML</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strong[span/@class='dates']">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="strong/span[@class='dates']">
  <date>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </date>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform this input document ...

```
<newsItem>
  <inlineXml>
    <h2>Calendar</h2> 
    <p><strong><span class="dates">June 16-18:</span>National Conference, Denver</strong></p>
    <p><strong><span class="dates">June 19-21:</span>Local Event, Chicago</strong></p>
  </inlineXml>
</newsItem>
```

... into this output html page ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Inline XML</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <newsItem>
         <inlineXml>
            <h2>Calendar</h2>
            <p>
               <date>June 16-18:</date>National Conference, Denver
            </p>
            <p>
               <date>June 19-21:</date>Local Event, Chicago
            </p>
         </inlineXml>
      </newsItem>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Some advice

1. There is no reason to be constrained to XSLT 1.0, You can
   upgrade to XSLT 2.0, even on a browser platform (courtesy of Saxon
   CE).
2. If your `date` element is intended to be a microformat,
   you should consider the [html 5 element `time`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/time.html).

Comment: The result is actually XML. Don't be fooled by the HTML tags. We are importing this from a CMS intended for web output, but the result will be a print file based in Adobe InDesign. So, the tags I'm using are irrelevant. The structure I posted above is what I wanted. Thanks